# mingw/msys2 build and link to dll without version number

Tags: dll, mingw, msys2

I'm building pjsip with mingw/msys2 and it keeps building dlls with .2 after them (.dll.2 files) as well as .dll files. If I delete the .dll.2 files that are built and try and build my program my program will STILL link to the .dll.2 versions and complain that they don't exists.

Command I run to build pjsip:

```
    ./configure CFLAGS="${MAKEFLAGS}" CXXFLAGS="${MAKEFLAGS}" \
            --build=${MINGW_CHOST} \
            --host=${MINGW_CHOST} \
            --target=${MINGW_CHOST} \
            --prefix="${OUT_PREFIX}" \
            --disable-openh264 \
            --disable-v4l2 \
            --disable-ffmpeg \
            --enable-libsamplerate \
            --disable-video \
            --enable-shared \
            --disable-static \
            --disable-libyuv \
            --with-external-speex \
            --with-gnutls
```

I can see in the build output that it builds dll.2 and then links them

```
ln -sf libpjsua2.dll.2 ../lib/libpjsua2.dll
```

How can I make my probgram only depend on the .dll and not the .dll.2?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to go (`grep`, perhaps) through the Makefile.am files, find the rule for libpjsua2, and modify it to remove the .2 'extension'. My guess is that the lib extension and integer 'extension' will not be hard-coded, so just search for libpjsua2. You can also remove the `ln -sf` bit at this point. Any changes you make to any files should be saved to a copy (or, you can `diff`) outside of the source/build directories so that you can reapply the changes if you ever download and unpack the source again.

The reason that you are running into this issue is that, at link time, the symbolic link is resolved and the *actual* name of the library is used. No amount of removing libraries is going to change this. Based only on the information you have given, it seems you might be misunderstanding what is actually being built: libpjsua2.dll is *not* a library in and of itself, rather a link to libpjsua2.dll.2. When you delete libpjsua2.dll.2, you are deleting the actual library, libpjsua2.dll points nowhere, and you end up with a "not found" error.